# How long time does it take to sync a rolling node on Carthage net?

Tags: node, syncing

I am running a node on a VPS on google cloud.

CPU: Intel Xeon (2) @ 2.300GHz
Memory: 2736MiB / 7476MiB

The docker data is located on an SSD.

It is currently at 2019-12-09T17:43:25Z (I just started). When can I expect it to be up to date?

Comment: If no one is able to answer, perhaps you should ask the same question for main net, and approximate the test net syncronization time from this answer?